# How to redirect a IIS url with a query string

Tags: redirect, iis

I am looking for redirecting a url in IIS from [www.abc.com/mysurvey.aspx?mysurveyid=100](http://www.abc.com/mysurvey.aspx?mysurveyid=100) to [www.abc.com/mysurvey.aspx?mysurveyid=101](http://www.abc.com/mysurvey.aspx?mysurveyid=101)

Could you please tell me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this below rule to implement your retirement:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/mysurvey.aspx" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="mysurveyid=100" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/mysurvey.aspx?mysurveyid=101" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```